# How to concatenate str and convert to a dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, dictionary

```
import numpy as np

a_var = np.array([1,2,3,5,67,9])
b_var = np.array([1,3,3,7,67,9])
b_var = np.array([1,5,3,7,77,10])
mydict = []

for i in dir():
    if i.endswith(_var):
        mydict += i
```

I got so many variables, I want the result of

```
mydict = {'a_var':a_var,'b_var':b_var,'b_var':b_var}.
```

Is there any way to achieve it?

Many thanks

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals

Comment: This is generally not the best idea. You'd be better starting with a dictionary instead of trying to convert all the variables to a dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `locals()`:

```
import numpy as np
a_var = np.array([1,2,3,5,67,9])
b_var = np.array([1,3,3,7,67,9])
b_var = np.array([1,5,3,7,77,10])

mydict = {}
for i in dir():
    if i.endswith('_var'):
        mydict.update({i:locals()[i]})
print(mydict)
```

Or, a `dict` comprehension:

```
mydict = {i:locals()[i] for i in dir() if i.endswith('_var')}
```

---

---

I do recommend this instead, which will give the same result:

```
import numpy as np

mydict = {}

mydict['a_var'] = np.array([1,2,3,5,67,9])
mydict['b_var'] = np.array([1,3,3,7,67,9])
mydict['b_var'] = np.array([1,5,3,7,77,10])

print(mydict)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the variables defined in the current context with the python built-in function locals(). It is a dict.

see https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals

You can get all the variables that end with '_var' by dict comprehension from the locals() dict:

```
{k:v for k,v in locals().items() if k.endswith('_var')}
```

Comment: Although michcio1234's comment on the original question makes a good point. If you want a dict of your variables, this is a red flag. Consider rewriting the code to use a dict in the first place.